# Convert array to key/value array

Tags: javascript, arrays

Im trying to convert a "simple" array that looks like this:

```
arr = [143.17, 174.45, 55.3]
```

To an array of objects in this format:

```
 Today = new Date();
    newArr =   [ 
        { key: Today, value: 143.17 },
        { key: Today + 1, value: 174.45 },
        { key: Today + 2, value: 55.3}]
```

Im hoping to create a function to which I can pass the original array and have it return the new one:

```
objArr = function CreateObjArr(arr){


 return newArr
}
```

Thank you

Comment: I don't really know where to start. But you are right. I could try to convert a single value into an object first.

Comment: what you want is not a key/value structure. the key/value is so organized, that the key is the access property of an object for a value. eg `{ day1: 1.2, day2: 1.1, day3: 1.4 }`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`Array.prototype.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) function

```
var newArr = arr.map(function(v, i) {
  return { key: Today + i, value: v };
});
```